# How to insert an image in a question?

Tags: support, images

I see graphs/charts/images appearing regularly in a post. How do I upload it to CV, and how do I place it in a text? I read the help pages on formatting, but still couldn't figure out.

Comment: Press the "image" icon (in the controls above the answer box) and follow the directions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Comment: I've tried clicking on the upvote, but it just takes me to the image ;-).

Comment: @gung Yes it does. Just checked the answer.

Comment: +1 for professional artwork (I'd use MS Paint for it) ;)